NetworkManager keeps restarting
My server running Ubuntu 20.04 recently became very slow. It has been running for two years without any problems prior to this. When connected to it over ssh, simply typing a command takes a long time due to it lagging, however i do not loose connection to it.
From /var/log/syslog I can see that the NetworkManager restarts constantly, sometimes several times each second:
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9223] device (ens27f0np0): carrier: link connected
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9236] device (ens27f0np0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 30 13:49:10 ross kernel: [16579.043767] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9399] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9400] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9400] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed no lease
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9401] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:10 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069750.9489] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed new lease, address=10.49.144.33
May 30 13:49:11 ross kernel: [16579.893774] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6225] device (ens27f0np0): carrier: link connected
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6237] device (ens27f0np0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 30 13:49:12 ross kernel: [16580.743913] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6399] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6400] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6400] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed no lease
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6401] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:12 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069752.6484] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed new lease, address=10.49.144.33
May 30 13:49:13 ross kernel: [16581.443982] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2227] device (ens27f0np0): carrier: link connected
May 30 13:49:14 ross kernel: [16582.344082] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2239] device (ens27f0np0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2520] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2520] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2520] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed no lease
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2521] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:14 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069754.2616] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed new lease, address=10.49.144.33
May 30 13:49:14 ross kernel: [16582.994191] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
May 30 13:49:15 ross kernel: [16583.894125] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7728] device (ens27f0np0): carrier: link connected
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7749] device (ens27f0np0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7919] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7920] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7920] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed no lease
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.7921] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 30 13:49:15 ross NetworkManager[1491]: <info>  [1717069755.8024] dhcp4 (ens27f0np0): state changed new lease, address=10.49.144.33
May 30 13:49:16 ross kernel: [16584.644341] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down

From dmesg I get the same error:
[Thu May 30 14:03:50 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:03:51 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
[Thu May 30 14:03:52 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:03:54 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
[Thu May 30 14:03:55 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:04:00 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
[Thu May 30 14:04:00 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:04:06 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
[Thu May 30 14:04:07 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:04:17 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down
[Thu May 30 14:04:18 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link up
[Thu May 30 14:04:48 2024] mlx5_core 0000:4c:00.0 ens27f0np0: Link down

I have updated all ubuntu drivers, and upgraded the system to 22.04, but the problem persists.
We have replaced the network cable, without it making a difference.
I would appreciate any suggestion.

If you also changed the router/switch port when you changed the cable, then you should make sure hat you have the latest firmware and driver updates for your Mellanox network card (mlx5_core driver).
Visit the Mellanox support site to download the latest firmware for your card.Then:
sudo apt-get install mstflint

Use mstflint to update your card.
However, it sounds to me that you've already tried with drivers, then I would have gone directly to try the following:
Sometimes NetworkManager settings can cause issues. What I have done in those weird cases is to disable NetworkManager for the problematic interface and manage it directly via systemd-networkd.
Disable NetworkManager for ens27f0np0:
sudo nmcli dev set ens27f0np0 managed no

Then add create /etc/systemd/network/10-ens27f0np0.network and paste this code:
[Match]
Name=ens27f0np0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

Make sure everything is correctly written, it's case sensitive!
Then, restart network services:
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved

Then, add a udev rule to disable Ethernet power saving which can sometimes cause link flaps.
Create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-disable-ethernet-powersave.rules with:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="ens27f0np0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/ethtool -s ens27f0np0 wol d"

Then reload the udev rules:
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger

Sometimes issues can be mitigated by adjusting the MTU size:
sudo ip link set dev ens27f0np0 mtu 1500

Good luck!
